# CodeIgniter Bonfire - Access Separate Module Table

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok, so I have a instance of CI Bonfire running (love it). I'm running into an issue with the structure that I can't seem to work around.

What I want to do is have two separate tables (which are powered by two separate modules), access eachothers data. I have two tables/modules called "Toolkits" & "Toolkit Items".

**Toolkits** = contain many toolkit items
**Toolkit Items** = belong to many toolkits

How do I route that so I can query the toolkit_items table from within the toolkits module folder? Is that even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider using phpactiverecord sparks? Check getsparks.com and phpactiverecord.org.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a module model from a module by simply

```
$this->load->model('toolkits/toolkits_model', null, true);
```